# Splitting a multiline block of text with regular expressions in c# into a matchcollection

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to break apart a database field containing free-form text using regular expressions in a C# application. Added comments simply appends a persons comments to the end. This is the sample format:

```
Bob Smith [21-Mar-2013 10:46:02 AM]: this that and the other thing

followed by some linefeeds and somesuch

Alexey Jones [08-Jul-2013 1:44:59 PM]: and here is some other comment that I, Alexey deemed worthy to put into the system

I also like using the enter key

Kim Katillicus [09-Jun-2014 2:34:43 PM]: Don't forget about my comments
```

The intent is that Alexey wants to see an output of his comments and not the comments of the others (This will be output to a static report). I am trying to bring back a match collection using variations of the following regex pattern:

```
^(.*\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}.*(AM|PM)\]:\s[\s\S]*)*
```

I have only been able to get one big blob containing everything or separate matches with just the first line from each persons entry. I am looking for aid in fixing this pattern. Not sure if I am getting close with what I have, or am barking up the wrong tree.

Note: I am testing my expressions with Expresso. At the moment I have the multiline switch checked.

Comment: Will a comment always be on a single line? If so I can provide a simpler and better performing solution.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal It seems pretty clear from the question text that the OP needs a multiline solution.

Comment: So in the above text, there should be `3` separate matches, correct?

Comment: @AustinMullins yeah although I don't actually see any reason to have returns in each comment data. Where to put newlines imo is the responsibility of the display layer, the db should just have the raw data. I should be able to split on newline then take lines containing the desired name and be good to go. At least that is what I think would be ideal.

Comment: Please show your desired output, otherwise we are blind-guessing. Seeing your desired output would be very very helpful. :)

Comment: The desired outcome is to have 3 matches in a matchcollection containing the full string for the users text entry. This needs to be used later in a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
[\s\S]*
```

Which says "match anything that either is or isn't white space 0 or more times". This would include absolutely everything after the first occurrence of the beginning of your expression.

It seems to me that the answer requires more logic than can be expressed with a single regular expression. For example, as @evanmcdonnal pointed out, you could split on newline characters and then match each line against your preamble RegEx, merging lines into a single comment until the next match. Here's a C# approach:

```
public static class CommentsExtractor
{
    private static Regex preambleExpression =
        new Regex(@"^.*\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}.*(AM|PM)\]:\s");

    public static List<string> CommentsFromText(string text)
    {
        var comments = new List<string>();

        var lines = text.Split(new char[]{'\n', '\r'},
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var currentComment = new StringBuilder();
        bool anyMatches = false;

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var match = preambleExpression.Match(line);

            // If we see a new preamble, it's time to push
            //  the current comment into the list.
            // However, the first time through, we don't have
            //  any data, so we'll skip it.
            if(match.Success)
            {
                if (anyMatches)
                {
                    comments.Add(currentComment.ToString());
                    currentComment.Clear();
                }
                anyMatches = true;
            }

            currentComment.AppendLine(line);
        }

        // Now we need to push the last comment
        comments.Add(currentComment.ToString());

        return comments;
    }
}
```

A working example WPF application is available on [Github](https://github.com/amullins83/CommentsExtractor).

Comment: Thanks Austin. I was thinking of something similar using the basic match to get a list of indexes and split it up from there, but I think you solution a lot cleaner. I was hoping there was a sexier way with Rexex, but see your point about the \s\S. I guess I was thinking there might be a way to say "Match based on the name/date + any text until you hit the next match".Thanks to everyone else who commented.